# How to convert 4 bytes hex to decimal manually

Tags: binary, hex

I am doing a CTF challenge. I open a broken BMP image file with a hex editor (HexFiend). I highlight 4 bytes in hex `8E262C00`. In the bottom, HexFiend shows their value in decimal `2893454`. However, I use online hex to decimal converting tool, their value is `2384866304`.

Do anyone know how HexFiend comes up with `2893454`?. I believe it is a correct answer, because that is the size of the file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the endianness of the file.

A binary encoded file can be encoded with small or big endian. The difference is which succession the single bytes have, i.e. if you read them from left or from right. Note that the order of bits almost always is big endian. The natural way of reading is big ending; the bytes are stores as you would expect it. `8E262C00` becomes `8E 26 2C 00`. This file, however, seems to be stored in small endian format. The order is flipped. In other words; `8E262C00` now becomes `00 2C 26 8E` which then results in the decimal representation of `2893454`

Comment: This is the first time I have to deal with endianness. I wonder how can I do programming smoothy for years without ever running into problem relating to endianness. I work with high-level programming language only though. Is there a way operating system, files, programming languages take care of endianness without developer ever worry about them?

Comment: Usually, yes, the operating system and (more importantly) high-level programming languages take care of a lot of problems. For example, the RAM itself could be aligned big endian or little endian (both bit-wise and byte-wise), however you usually won't have to deal with it. I have come across issues with small/little endian in 3 scenarios: a) Low-level programming, potentially going down to assembly level b) Network stuff c) binary files such as yours. Most languages have tools, however, to easily convert from/to big/little endian

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the Big Endian and Little Endian things.

You should check out this online converting tool, BMP file format is the Little Endian, but i think the tool maybe convert it by Big Endian method.

try it: https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/

Comment: you can also change the Endianness in vscode hex editor.